# Google SignUp/ SignIn with Flutter + Back4App

Tags: flutter, google-signin, back4app

**Below is the used code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:parse_server_sdk_flutter/parse_server_sdk.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  Future<void> _signUpGoogle() async {
    // loading = true;

    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
        scopes: ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']);

    sigInGoogle() async {
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication = await account.authentication;
      final ParseResponse response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
          'google',
          google(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id,
              authentication.accessToken.toString(), authentication.idToken));

      // print('response.error' + response.error.toString());
      // print('response.results' + response.results.toString());
      // print('response.results' + response.statusCode.toString());
      print(response.toString());
      if (response.success) {
        print('parse google signin successs');
        print(response.success);
      } else {
        print('parse google SignIn Failed');
        print('response.error:  ' + response.error.toString());
        // print(google(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id,
        //     authentication.accessToken.toString(), authentication.idToken));
      }
    }

    sigInGoogle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.login),
        onPressed: _signUpGoogle,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Below are the logs:**

I/flutter (23392): Instance of 'ParseResponse'

I/flutter (23392): parse google SignIn Failed

I/flutter (23392): response.error:

I/flutter (23392): ----

I/flutter (23392): ParseException (Type: ObjectNotFound) :

I/flutter (23392): Code: 101

I/flutter (23392): Message: Google auth is invalid for this user.----

**Please help to resolve this.**

Comment: Have you setup Google auth in Back4App dashboard? You can take a look at this guie: https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/sign-in-with-google

Comment: This page explains the process for setting up google auth in b4a for a WEB app. Can you share the steps for an IOS and android app?

FYI: OAuth 2.0 Client IDs are set up for android and IOS apps.

Please help

Comment: There are code examples for android and iOS at the end of this guide.

Comment: Yes, there are
but I am developing in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your parameters are the wrong way around when passing to the 'google' data type. The parameters are;

```
Map<String, dynamic> google(String token, String id, String idToken)
```

Using your code but passing through in this order,

```
google(authentication.accessToken.toString(), _googleSignIn.currentUser!.id, authentication.idToken!));
```

Does the trick for me